# apt upgrade failing on ubuntu 18.04 and 20.04 servers

Tags: apt, upgrade, updates

Hello I am getting the following two errors which is preventing me from updating the servers.

```
Err:1 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/main amd64 apache2-data all 2.4.41-4ubuntu3.13
   500 Internal Server Error (IP: 91.189.91.39 80)
Err:2 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/main amd64 linux-headers-5.4.0-139 all
   Connection failed (IP: 185.125.190.36 80)
E: Failed to fetch...
```

This is occurring on four 18.04 servers and two 20.04 servers. The only difference on the 18.04 servers is the name is bionic instead of focal.
I have tried sudo apt clean && sudo apt update which works and then sudo apt clean && sudo apt upgrade -y which fails on the above every time.

I worked with our firewall vendor and they cannot see any problems. I have tried dns suggestions and source list suggestions from stack overflow and ask Ubuntu to no avail. This all was working until about 2 weeks ago.

Any suggestions will be greatly appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: I would wonder why archive.ubuntu.com is resolving to two different IPs.

Comment: I was curious about that but didn't think it was a problem because if do an nslookup archive.ubuntu.com both of those IP's are returned. I also tried the same steps on a machine outside of our network and firewall and get the same results on the nslookup.

Answer (score 0):

Just been fighting this same issue with multiple mirrors, but I just sussed it! Use an `https` mirror.

I was only trying `http` mirrors but I found this kinda unrelated post that gave me a hint to try `https`: https://www.mail-archive.com/debian-user-dutch@lists.debian.org/msg06283.html

So I tried this mirror and it worked! https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+mirror/mirror.pulsant.com-archive

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Thanks. I did also try https and that resulted with the same errors. In my case it turned out to be something on our firewall that our security team resolved. I don't much about that side and fortunately it is working now.